# Filtering for events occurring within X minutes of each other within Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, kibana-7

Is there a filter/query that can be used to find events occurring within say, 5 minutes of each other? I'm specifically interested in seeing details of event_id X, but only if event_id Y also occurs within a 5 minute timeframe (earlier or later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per a suggestion on Reddit, it looks like this can only be achieved through EQL - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/eql.html